# QTableWidget Current Selection Change Signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

What's the signal of a QTableWidget when the current selection changes and how can I assign a slot to it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want the [`itemSelectionChanged`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#itemSelectionChanged) signal:

> This signal is emitted whenever the selection changes.

You can use this by doing something like this:

```
self.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.print_row)
```

This will call `self.print_row` (which is a function you create) every time the selection changes.

---

A very basic example:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

lista = ['r1c1', 'r1c2', 'r1c3']
listb = ['r2c1', 'r2c2', 'r1c3']
listc = ['r3c1', 'r3c2', 'r3c3']
mystruct = {'row1':lista, 'row2':listb, 'row3':listc}

class MyTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, thestruct, *args):
        QtGui.QTableWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.data = thestruct
        n = 0
        for key in self.data:
            m = 0
            for item in self.data[key]:
                newitem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(item)
                self.setItem(m, n, newitem)
                m += 1
            n += 1
        self.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.print_row)

    def print_row(self):
        items = self.selectedItems()
        print(str(items[0].text()))

def main(args):
    app = QtGui.QApplication(args)
    table = MyTable(mystruct, 3, 3)
    table.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

---

This creates a table like this:

[image: UI]

When you select any of the cells, it will print out the text in the cell. As a note, this print function assumes that you only make one selection at a time. The `selectedItems()` function returns a list of selected items. I am only using the first index in this example.